# Sorting buffer lines by a field

Tags: elisp

How can I sort the following buffer data by the second field (author's name) or third field (published date)?  I'd like a pure elisp solution, so I'd rather not have a solution that used M-|.

```
Tom Sawyer|Mark Twain|1876
Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone|JK Rowling|1997
Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince|JK Rowling|2009
The Da Vinci Code|Dan Brown|2003
A Short History of Nearly Everything|Bill Bryson|2003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function uses [`sort-regexp-fields`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html) to do the work:

```
(defun my-sort-fields (n)
  "Sort lines by | delimted fields"
  (interactive "nWhich field: ")
  (sort-regexp-fields nil
                      (format "^\\([^|]*|\\)\\{%d\\}\\([^|\n]*\\)\\(|[^|\n]*\\)*$" (- n 1))
                      (format "\\2" )
                      (point-min)
                      (point-max)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty much like an `org-mode` table. Can you just add a `|` to the beginning and end of every line? Then you can use the inbuilt `org-sort` command to sort by a column. If you *have* to be in another major-mode, you can use `orgtbl-mode` as a minor mode for just that region.

Comment: This does work.  I was hoping for the actual elisp code.  I can "C-h f org-sort" and look through that code provided in the link.